# How hard is it to generate a simultaneous MD5 and SHA1 collision?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-256, sha-1, md5

I was recently reading that MD5 is "broken" because it's pretty easy to generate collisions (like `2^(L/2)`). And the SHA1 (theoretically) fares no better. The solution seems to be hash algorithms that are very slow in comparison.

I am wondering why can't people combine these *fast* algorithms to get the best of both *security* and *speed*? What would be the time complexity to generate a simultaneous MD5 and SHA1 collision? And if it's hard enough, would these make a viable candidate for collision resistant hash applications?

*(By simultaneous collision I mean generating a string with same MD5 and SHA1)*

Comment: Do you have a specific use case in mind where you would like to use two different hash functions?

Comment: @Jedi: I believe his idea is "if we generate a hash of the form $MD5(M) || SHA(M)$, wouldn't this be stronger than MD5 or SHA1 individually?"

Comment: Yes, it would definitely lead to fewer collisions. But, there are other hashing algorithms which are faster and have better collision resistance (than MD5...), which might be more suitable. Basically `The solution seems to be hash algorithms that are very slow in comparison` may not be an accurate assertion.

Comment: Possible duplicate post from [sister site](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83881/is-using-the-concatenation-of-multiple-hash-algorithms-more-secure)

Comment: SHA-1 collisions have now been found. SHA-1 is still slightly less broken than MD5. But SHA-1 is now officially broken in practice as well as in theory. https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Surprisingly enough, it would appear that generating a simultaneous collision wouldn't be that much more expensive than generating a single collision for SHA-1.

The basic idea is to form a $2^{64}$ wide multicollision on SHA-1; that is, $2^{64}$ distinct messages that all SHA-1 hash to the same value.  We can do this by using Joux's idea of forming finding 64 different colliding blocks $B_{i, 0}, B_{i, i}$ such that all sequences $B_{0, a}, B_{1, b}, B_{2, c}, ..., B_{63, z}$ all share the same SHA-1 hash; this can be done by finding 64 successive SHA-1 collisions.  The best estimate on finding a single SHA-1 collision is $2^{61}$ SHA-1 compression function calls (Stevens); hence the effort to find 64 such collisions is $2^{67}$ compression function calls.

Once we have such a $2^{64}$ wide multicollision, we just do an MD5 hash of each, and look for an MD5 collision; this takes $2^{65}$ MD5 compression function calls, and yields a collision with good probability.

This yields a simultaneous SHA-1 and MD5 collision with an expected $2^{67}$ computational effort.

Comment: What I find potentially prohibitive is storage complexity or storage costs. The naive approach is some (distributed) `Map<Hash, Preimage>` structure with up to 2^64 items. It can be optimized in various ways, but the **lower estimate** for the naive structure is 128*2^64 bits = 2^71 bits = 2^68 bytes = 2^28 TiB. Maybe further optimization similar to rainbow tables is possible, but I am curious how far could we go in some time/space tradeoff.

Comment: @v6ak: I suspect that you could use a Rho cycle-finding algorithm to find a collision with limited memory, at the cost of a (moderate) constant factor to the number of MD5 hashes required...

Comment: @poncho Isn't the number of MD5 compressions to hash $2^{64}$ messages, each $64$ blocks long, closer to $2^{70}$? (And by the way, the [SHAttered paper](//shattered.io/static/shattered.pdf) mentions $2^{63.1}$ SHA1 compressions, so it seems the earlier estimates of $2^{61}$ were slightly optimistic.)

Comment: @yyyyyyy: Actually, you can optimize the MD5 compression step, as you don't need to MD5 hash each 64 (actually, 128, the SHA-1 collision finds 2 block collisions I believe) block segment from scratch; the first $2k$ segments are repeated between $2^{64-k}$ different hashes...

Comment: @poncho Good point, I hadn't realized this optimization has such a big impact. So the actual cost is $2\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{64}2^i \approx 2^{66}$ MD5 compressions?